# Capacitor v3: Blank page when open on andriod

Tags: android, capacitor

On a new Angular project with minimal dependencies it **works perfectly**, if I install the capacitor on an existing project a little bigger when running the script (the same):
`"run-android": "ng b --prod && npx cap copy && npx cap open android"`, I **receive a blank page without any error or warning in VS Code terminal or in Android Studio in build process**.

**capacitor.config.ts**

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.acs.gradinite',
  appName: 'gradinite',
  webDir: 'dist/materialui',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  android: {
    allowMixedContent: true
  }
};

export default config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "materialui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "run-android": "ng b --prod && npx cap copy && npx cap open android",
    "run-ios": "ng b --prod && npx cap copy && npx cap open ios"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@acs/infrastructura-standard": "^1.0.9",
    "@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.0.2",
    "@capacitor/angular": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.0.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.0.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.20",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.11.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "ng-swagger-gen": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

**generated files: build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**run script**

```
    $ npm run run-android

> materialui@0.0.0 run-android C:\Taskbar\Aplicatii\gradi-ui\angularui\angularui
> ng b --prod && npx cap copy && npx cap open android


chunk {} runtime.e227d1a0e31cbccbf8ec.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.beccaf513d6405657545.js (main) 2.67 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.a4021de53358bb0fec14.js (polyfills) 36.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.09211cbab8a67b19db36.css (styles) 213 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2021-06-29T05:44:38.301Z - Hash: 6eb75a02602e789c479b - Time: 46445ms

WARNING in C:\Taskbar\Aplicatii\gradi-ui\angularui\angularui\src\app\app.module.ts depends on 'angular2-signaturepad'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
√ Copying web assets from materialui to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 23.83ms
√ Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 1.14ms
√ copy android in 49.87ms
√ Copying web assets from materialui to ios\App\App\public in 12.61ms
√ Creating capacitor.config.json in ios\App\App in 615.10μp
√ copy ios in 21.81ms
√ copy web in 528.40μp
[info] Opening Android project at: android.
```

Comment: can you share the whole script file?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the issue was at the routing file, I had to add from the start:

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  
  { 
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent 
  },
```